# Position of the nominative in a sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order

> 1. Einmal hat **sie** mich zum Kaffee eingeladen.
>   2. Plötzlich guckten mich **alle** an.

Can you explain why the nominatives in both sentences have changed positions?
"Sie" came just after the verb "hat" in Sentence number 1, while "alle" did not come after the verb "guckten" in sentence number 2.

Comment: Because word order in German is quite flexible? V2 could be a keyword for you.

Comment: Actually, the position of the reflexive pronoun _sich_ has changed here...  Have a look here: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39345/position-of-sich-in-a-subordinate-clause

Answer (score 3):

German does not have fixed positions for subjects and objects. Nevertheless, there are some regularities that can be observed as far as neutral word order is concerned. An overview is given by canoo [here](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Stellungsfeld/Mittelfeld/index.html).

The word order in your first sentence can be explained by the fact that the subject is a personal pronoun. These often appear immediately to the right of the fronted finite verb, with subjects preceding accusative objects preceding dative objects.

In the second sentence, *alle* behaves just like a noun and appears to the right of the personal pronoun. Interestingly, the neutral order for nouns (and pronouns that are not personal or reflexive pronouns) is subjects before dative objects before accusative objects.

A more complete exposition is given by the page I linked. Also, don't forget that word orders contradicting these regularities are nearly always possible (given the right circumstances). Your second sentence could be rewritten as *Plötzlich guckten alle mich an* just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The **neutral** word order for subject and objects of the *Mittelfeld* is

> … nominative pronoun – accusative pronoun – dative pronoun – nominative noun – dative  noun – accusative noun …

As long as there aren't ambiguities, you may deviate from that *neutral* order to create special emphasis.

> Einmal hat sie mich zum Kaffee eingeladen. *(neutral)*
>
> Einmal hat mich **sie** zum Kaffee eingeladen. *(Yes, **that** person!)*
>
> Plötzlich guckten mich alle an. *(neutral)*
>
> Plötzlich guckten alle **mich** an. *(Yes, **me**!)*

Comment: But the second sentence sounds pretty weird, even if it is meant to stress **sie**. I don't think I would change the word order here.

Comment: Yes. But this is mostly because of the simple example. A real sentence would have modal particles dropped in: *Einmal hat mich dann doch sie zum Kaffee eingeladen.*

Comment: even then, I would say (write): "Einmal hat *sie* mich dann doch zum Kaffee eingeladen". I would use a second sentence to stress that it was her who invited me, or when speaking, I would use intonation.

Comment: But that means a different thing. The item *dann doch sie* is different from *mich dann doch*.

Comment: no, the stress is still on *sie*: "sie mich dann doch" == "mich dann doch sie"

Comment: No, because the modal particle *dann doch* means a different thing if it precedes or follows an item.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis "Einmal hat mich **sogar sie** eingeladen" is perfectly fine though. (Although "Einmal hat sogar sie mich eingeladen" is also good.)

Comment: @sgf: Both are fine, although I prefer the latter.